# z-axis label on Axes3D

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

How can I define the label for the other axis?

```
X, Y = meshgrid(gammas, psis)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
ax = Axes3D(fig)
pylab.xlabel("$\gamma$ (radian) ")
pylab.ylabel("$\psi$ (radian) ")
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, -x,rstride=1.14, cstride=1.14)
ax.view_init(30, 45)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the z-label using the `.set_zlabel()` method of `ax`:

```
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
```

As I think I mentioned to you before, the `rstride` and `cstride` arguments to `plot_surface` need to be integers.